# Makefile not writing files to /usr/local/lib/ in cygwin

Tags: makefile, cygwin

I ran a particular Makefile on my Lubuntu machine, and it created a couple directories of files in my /usr/local/lib directory.

Tonight I'm trying to create a similar setup in a cygwin window on my Windows 10 machine. Same Makefile, but the /usr/local/lib directory ends up empty. So when I run a different Makefile later on that wants to call these /usr/local/lib libraries, it fails.

What could I be doing wrong? Is there an environment variable that needs to be set such that the /usr/loal/lib directory can be written to during the make?

Thanks.

Update: I just figured out that I can install Ubuntu as an application in Windows https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/ , and my makefile install is working great now. No problems at all, so it appears to be a cygwin problem only. That being said, here is my make file:

```
#! /usr/bin/make -f
# -*- make -*-
#
# Main gcc Makefile.
# This makefile is maintained by Greg King <greg.king4@verizon.net>.

# Goals that are supported by the cc65 package
.PHONY: all bins libs docs samples tests clean zap
.PHONY: uninstall install install-bins install-libs install-docs install-samps

# If SYS is defined on this makefile's command-line, then we want it to go
# to "samples" and "tests", but not to the other rules.  So, we disable a
# feature of GNU make that would have given ${SYS} to every sub-make.
#MAKEOVERRIDES=
# (That trick has been disabled.)

# To compile with custom make-options, set them here; for example:
#MAKEOPTS = -j 2 CFLAGS=-O4 CC=clang
MAKEOPTS =

# The install prefix and directories
prefix      = /usr/local
exec_prefix = $(prefix)

bindir      = $(exec_prefix)/bin
datadir     = $(prefix)/share
docdir      = $(datadir)/doc
libdir      = $(exec_prefix)/lib

CC65_DOC    = $(docdir)/cc65
CC65_HOME   = $(libdir)/cc65

CA65_INC    = $(CC65_HOME)/asminc
CC65_INC    = $(CC65_HOME)/include
LD65_CFG    = $(CC65_HOME)/cfg
LD65_LIB    = $(CC65_HOME)/lib
LD65_OBJ    = $(CC65_HOME)/obj

# Programs

MKDIR       = mkdir -m 755

# BSD-like install-script/-program
INSTALL     = make/install-sh

INSTALL_DATA    = $(INSTALL) -c -m 644
INSTALL_PROG    = $(INSTALL) -c -m 755
INSTALL_STRIP   = $(INSTALL_PROG) -s

# This file-name extension is needed on DOS/Windows systems.
ifdef COMSPEC
EXT = .exe
endif

# Rules

# The sample and library-test programs must be compiled for only one platform
# at a time.  So, those rules are done automatically only when a user names
# a system on the command-line.  (A user can do those rules with their
# defaults by putting "all samples tests" on the command-line.)
#
all:    bins libs docs $(SYS:%=samples tests)

bins:
    @$(MAKE) -C src -f make/gcc.mak $(MAKEOPTS) \
      CA65_INC=\\\"${CA65_INC}/\\\" CC65_INC=\\\"${CC65_INC}/\\\" \
      LD65_CFG=\\\"${LD65_CFG}/\\\" LD65_LIB=\\\"${LD65_LIB}/\\\" \
      LD65_OBJ=\\\"${LD65_OBJ}/\\\"

libs:
    @$(MAKE) -C libsrc

# This rule won't try to generate HTML files
# if a host system doesn't have LinuxDoc Tools.
docs:
    @if linuxdoc -B check doc/index >/dev/null 2>&1; \
      then $(MAKE) -C doc $(MAKEOPTS) html; \
      else echo '"LinuxDoc Tools" is not installed; skipping HTML documentation.'; \
      fi

# Some platforms cannot compile all of the sample and library-test programs.
# So, these rules ignore errors.

samples:
    -@$(MAKE) -k -C samples prefix=$(prefix) $(SYS:%=SYS=%)

tests:
    -@$(MAKE) -k -C testcode/lib prefix=$(prefix) $(SYS:%=SYS=%)

clean zap:
    @$(MAKE) -C src -f make/gcc.mak $@
    @$(MAKE) -C libsrc $@
    @$(MAKE) -C doc $@
    @$(MAKE) -C samples $@
#   @$(MAKE) -C testcode/lib $@ $(SYS:%=SYS=%)

uninstall:  install-test
    cd $(bindir) && $(RM) ar65${EXT} ca65${EXT} cc65${EXT} cl65${EXT} \
      co65${EXT} da65${EXT} ld65${EXT} od65${EXT} grc65${EXT} ca65html
    $(RM) -R $(CC65_HOME) $(CC65_DOC)

install:    install-test install-dirs install-bins install-libs install-docs
    @echo
    @echo 'If you installed the files into non-default directories, then'
    @echo 'you might need to export some shell environment variables:'
    @echo
    @echo 'CC65_HOME=$(CC65_HOME)'
    @echo ' or'
    @echo 'CA65_INC=$(CA65_INC)'
    @echo 'CC65_INC=$(CC65_INC)'
    @echo 'LD65_CFG=$(LD65_CFG)'
    @echo 'LD65_LIB=$(LD65_LIB)'
    @echo 'LD65_OBJ=$(LD65_OBJ)'
    @echo
    @if [ -x $(bindir)/grc${EXT} ]; then \
      echo 'grc was renamed to grc65; but, a grc command is in your binaries directory.'; \
      echo "If that command is an old copy of CC65's program,"; \
      echo 'then you should use a "${MAKE} erase-grc" command to remove it.'; \
      fi

.PHONY: install-test
install-test:
    @if [ `id -u` != 0 ]; then \
      echo; \
      echo 'If you are denied permission to install or uninstall this package,'; \
      echo 'then you will need to do "make/gcc.mak install" or "make/gcc.mak uninstall"'; \
      echo 'as either the root user or an administrator.'; \
      echo; \
      fi 2>/dev/null

.PHONY: install-dirs
install-dirs:   $(bindir) $(datadir) $(docdir) $(libdir) \
        $(CC65_DOC) $(CC65_HOME) \
        $(CA65_INC) $(CC65_INC) \
        $(CC65_INC)/em $(CC65_INC)/geos $(CC65_INC)/joystick \
        $(CC65_INC)/mouse $(CC65_INC)/sys $(CC65_INC)/tgi \
        $(LD65_CFG) $(LD65_LIB) $(LD65_OBJ) \
        $(CC65_HOME)/emd $(CC65_HOME)/joy $(CC65_HOME)/mou \
        $(CC65_HOME)/ser $(CC65_HOME)/tgi

$(bindir) $(datadir) $(docdir) $(libdir) \
$(CC65_DOC) $(CC65_HOME) \
$(CA65_INC) $(CC65_INC) \
$(LD65_CFG) $(LD65_LIB) $(LD65_OBJ):
    $(MKDIR) -p $@ || $(MKDIR) $@

$(CC65_HOME)/% $(CC65_INC)/% $(CC65_DOC)/%:
    $(MKDIR) $@

install-bins:
    for f in ar65 ca65 cc65 cl65 co65 da65 ld65 od65 grc65 sp65; \
      do $(INSTALL_STRIP) src/$$f/$$f${EXT} $(bindir) || exit $$?; \
      done
    $(INSTALL_PROG) src/ca65html/ca65html $(bindir)

install-libs:
    for f in asminc/*.inc; \
      do $(INSTALL_DATA) $$f $(CA65_INC) || exit $$?; \
      done
    for f in include/*.h; \
      do $(INSTALL_DATA) $$f $(CC65_INC) || exit $$?; \
      done
    for d in em geos joystick mouse sys tgi; \
      do for f in include/$$d/*.h; \
        do $(INSTALL_DATA) $$f $(CC65_INC)/$$d || exit $$?; \
        done || exit $$?; \
      done
    for f in libsrc/*.lib; \
      do $(INSTALL_DATA) $$f $(LD65_LIB) || exit $$?; \
      done
    for f in libsrc/*-*.o; \
      do $(INSTALL_DATA) $$f $(LD65_OBJ) || exit $$?; \
      done
    for f in src/ld65/cfg/[!g]*-*.cfg; \
      do $(INSTALL_DATA) $$f $(LD65_CFG) || exit $$?; \
      done
    for d in emd joy mou ser tgi; \
      do for f in libsrc/*.$$d; \
        do $(INSTALL_DATA) $$f $(CC65_HOME)/$$d || exit $$?; \
        done || exit $$?; \
      done

install-docs:
    for f in src/ca65/macpack/*.mac; \
      do $(INSTALL_DATA) $$f $(CC65_DOC) || exit $$?; \
      done
    for f in readme.1st compile.txt CREDITS BUGS internal.txt newvers.txt; \
      do $(INSTALL_DATA) doc/$$f $(CC65_DOC) || exit $$?; \
      done
    if [ -f doc/index.htm* ]; \
      then for f in doc/*.htm*; \
        do $(INSTALL_DATA) $$f $(CC65_DOC) || exit $$?; \
        done; \
      fi

install-samps:  ${addprefix $(CC65_DOC)/, $(shell find samples -type d)}
    @$(MAKE) -C samples zap
    for d in `find samples -type d`; \
      do for f in $$d/*; \
        do if [ -f $$f ]; \
          then $(INSTALL_DATA) $$f $(CC65_DOC)/$$d || exit $$?; \
          fi; \
        done || exit $$?; \
      done

erase-grc:
    $(RM) $(bindir)/grc${EXT}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We can't hope to solve this without seeing the makefile. Did you write it? Do you know the person who did?

Comment: Beta, thank you so much. I just added the makefile in case anyone could benefit from seeing it. But I also updated to say that I've now installed Ubuntu as an application in Windows 10, and it's working great. No problem at all. So I'm all set. Thanks again.

Comment: What is `make/install-sh` ? Have you looked at the output of `make install` ? It probably can give an hint of the problem

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. When asking for help it is always better to provide the **exact** error message you have. Statements like _it does not work as expected_ are far less informative. Are you running `make install` with enough privileges to write in `/usr/local/bin` (which is usually protected against accidental write from regular users)?

Comment: Normally there shouldn't be any problem running a Makefile on Cygwin, but without knowing *specifically* what the problem is it's hard to say, especially without knowing what `make/install-sh` is doing.  It seems to be being used in a way that emulates the BSD `install` program which already comes built-in on most systems.  You could try using the standard `install` by running `make install INSTALL=`which install` and see if that works any better.

Comment: Hello, everyone. I appreciate all your responses. Not too long after I posted the question, I posted an update to it along with a message (see above) saying that for me, the problem is resolved. The problem only happens in Cygwin, and I am no longer using Cygwin. I'm instead using an Ubuntu window in Windows 10, and it's working great. I don't know why it didn't work in Cygwin, but I don't plan on working to further debug it. But thank you again for your comments. Maybe they will be helpful to the next person who has this problem.